# Vuejs generate elements from object inside components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, virtual-dom

I'm trying to create a component that will render elements inside VueJs virtual dom with a Vuex state.

The problem is I get this error but I don't understand why and how to fix it

> Avoid using observed data object as vnode data: {"class":"btn btn-default"}
>   Always create fresh vnode data objects in each render!

Inside my Vuex state I store and object where I define the elements properties

```
{
  type: 'a',
  config: {
    class: 'btn btn-default',
  },
  nestedElements: [
    {
      type: 'span',
      value: 'test',
    },
    {
      type: 'i',
    },
  ],
},
```

My components code look like

```
methods: {
  iterateThroughObject(object, createElement, isNestedElement = false) {
    const generatedElement = [],
          nestedElements = [];

    let parentElementConfig = {};

    for (const entry of object) {
      let nodeConfig = {};

      if (typeof entry.config !== 'undefined' && isNestedElement) {
        nodeConfig = entry.config;
      } else if (typeof entry.config !== 'undefined') {
        parentElementConfig = entry.config;
      }

      if (entry.nestedElements) {
        nestedElements.push(this.iterateThroughObject(entry.nestedElements, createElement, true));
      }

      if (!isNestedElement) {
        nodeConfig = parentElementConfig;
      }

      generatedElement.push(createElement(
        entry.type,
        nodeConfig === {} ? entry.value : nodeConfig,
        nestedElements
      ));
    }

    if (isNestedElement) {
      return generatedElement;
    }

    return createElement('ul', generatedElement);
  },
},
render(createElement) {
  const barToolsElements = this.$store.state.titleBar.barToolsElements;

  if (barToolsElements) {
    return this.iterateThroughObject(barToolsElements, createElement);
  }

  return false;
},
```

The error is produced when I try to pass inside my last `generatedElement.push()` definition.
Because `entry.value` is `{"class":"btn btn-default"}`.

I don't understand why it tell me to recreate a fresh Vnode object while this value is used only once.

Did I miss or misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be because you're passing references to objects in your store's state, which might lead inadvertently to their mutation. Try [creating deep clones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) of these objects when you pass them around, like for example ..

`nodeConfig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entry.config));`

`parentElementConfig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entry.config))`;

`nodeConfig === {} ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entry.value)) : nodeConfig,`

Comment: I'm using `cloneDeep` from lodash and it's work well

Comment: Ça va aussi marcher :)